# Can PICT handle independent parameters

Tags: testing, pairwise

Can PICT (=Pairwise Independent Combinatorial Testing) handle/model independent parameters.
For example in following input a and b are independent, so they should not be combined.

Input in PICT:
a: 1, 2, 3, 4
b: 5, 6, 7, 8

//some line which models the independence: a independent of b

Output, that I would expect:
a  b
1  5
2  6
3  7
4  8

This example, with only 2 parameters, of course normally would not make much sense, but it's illustrative.
The same could be applied to 3 parameters (a,b,c), where a is independent of b, but not c.
The main goal of declaring parameters as independent would be the reduce the number of tests.
I read the paper/user guide to PICT, but I didn't found any useful information.

Comment: Hi, welcome to SO. The most important thing on posting on SO, is to present your question clearly. Your question seems to be "Can PICT handle independent parameters" and you have answered it yourself with the 2 parameter a,b example.
Try and update your post with a more targeted question such as "how do PICT handle my (a,b,c) case" or "How do I minimize the number of tests in my (a,b,c) case?"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I will answer my question by myself:

The solution is to define submodels and set the default order from 2 (=pairwise) to 1 (= no combination).

---

For example parameter a = {a_1, a_2, a_3} should be independent of 

b = {b_1, b_2, b_3} and 

c = {c_1, ..., c_4}. 

Therefor I would expect 12 tests ((b x c) + a).

Resulting in the following input file: 

a: 1,2,3

b: 1,2,3

c: 1,2,3,4


{b,c}@2 


{b,c}@2 defines a submodel, consisting of b and c, which uses pairwise combination.

And running pict with the option: "/o:1".

Answer (score 0):

In PICT you can define conditions and achieve your goal to not combine them with the rest. You can add additional option as N/A and have something like this;

```
If [A] = '1' Then [B] = 'N/A';
```

This is one possible option to handle this case.